# String match function returns an array, but if converted to number, returns the matched number

Tags: javascript

Why

```js
console.log(
  "test3".match(/\d/)
);
```

Returns an array of elements, but converting it to a number:

```js
console.log(
  +"test3".match(/\d/)
);
```

Returns the number matched directly?

I thought it would throw an error.

Other thing I notice, using `typeof` before the first expression, it says "object", but even MDN says it's an Array.

Edit: I actually didn't confuse myself with the + operator or precedance, I was confused about the conversion of the array to a number haha. Thanks!

Comment: An array is an object.

Comment: It returns an array of *one* element. Using the `+` operator on the match result is the same as `Number(["3"])`, which casts the array to a string and parses it as a number. It wouldn't work with multiple matches. (But still wouldn't throw an error, just result in `NaN`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
+"test3".match(/\d/)
```

You might think it means `(+"test3").match(/\d/)` but it doesn't.

It actually translates to `+("test3".match(/\d/))`.

So the steps of execution becomes:

```
--> +("test3".match(/\d/))
--> +(["3"])
--> +(["3"].toString())
--> +("3")
--> 3
```

Therefore, no error is thrown.

You can read more about [operator precedence here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

Hope this clarify your confusion.

Comment: Oh okay I got it! I actually thought it was converting the entire array, the result of the match function.

Comment: But (correct me if I'm wrong), the match function returns an array with more items right? Not just one element array

Comment: @PatrickPassarella read more about operator precedence in the link I referenced above.

Comment: @PatrickPassarella `"test3".match(/\d/)` only return single-item array `["3"]` because there is no other digits _and_ there is no global flag in your regex.